# How Can I set statistics-Enabled to True for EJB and undertow In JBOSS EAP 7.1?

Tags: deployment, jboss, ejb, undertow, info

How can I  set Statistics-Enabled=True for /subsystem=undertow/servlet-container= default/server=default-server/http-listener=default ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is no function to enable statistics for a particular listener. But you can enable statistics for subsystem undertow.

To read attribute :

```
/subsystem=undertow:read-attribute(name=statistics-enabled)
```

To change the attribute :

```
/subsystem=undertow:write-attribute(name=statistics-enabled,value=true)
```

You may need to prefix the command with particular profile.

Reference for other commands to enable statistics : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKFH/com.ibm.apmaas.doc/install/jboss_config_agent_prereq_enable_web_statistics_collection.htm